# Library email alert is not working any more after migrate site collections from contentdbA to contentdbB

Tags: document-library, alert, migrate

I have migrated some site collections from contentdbA to contentdbB. I did this with a powershell command. After this I did an IIS reset. The site collections are working fine now. There is only one issue.

The email alert on the libraries are not working any more. Why do I have this issue and is there some solution?

Comment: check this one http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/sharepoint-alerts-not-working-troubleshooting-checklist.html .... # 17 is more relavant

Comment: what powershell code did you use to migrate over?